# Load balancer + CPU load manager to handle SIP connections?

Tags: load-balancing, qos, sip

I no longer have a landline and subscribed to a VoIP provider to have a landline phone number.

I prefer to use a softphone ([EyeBeam](http://www.counterpath.com/), the commercial version of XLite), but there are times when a call comes in while a big download/compiling is under way.

I was thinking of adding

1. a small load balancer between my PC and the ADSL router so as to provide QoS, where most of the bandwidth would be automatically reallocated to the SIP flow when a call comes in. Are Linux-moded routers like Linksys WRT* or Asus WL500* a good solution, or should I consider other hardware?
2. Is there a utility for XP/Vista that will automatically allocate most of the CPU to EyeBeam when it's in active use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if you are still interested:
-Qos: most of the routers has some kind of QoS. You have to find out the media (RTP) ports used by the softphone and increase it's priority
-CPU prioritization: i am using mizu softphone ([softphone download link](http://www.mizu-voip.com)). This softphone automatically increase it's process priority during calls so i don't have any issue even while my cpu is running at 100%